# Excel Power Query replace value if value starts with (nested, or multiple replacements to be made)

Tags: nested, powerquery, find-replace

I am very new to power query and for the most part am able to stumble around and achieve what I need to, but in this case the option of adding column after column and then removing all of the unwanted ones just feels too ugly.

I am trying to replace several different items in one column where there are several thousand rows.  Basically combining similar position titles in to a generic title:

Eg, all titles that begin with Supply Assistant to Supply Assistant, all titles that begin with NCC Rep to NCC Rep.

In excel this is simple using wildcards and a nested IF statement, but there are no wildcards in PQ.  Ideally I'd like to do it without adding a new column, but the closest I can get is by adding a new column.  It works for the first replace, but when I added the second one, although the first one still works, every other result is "Function".

```
    = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value1", "Title", each if Text.StartsWith([POS_TITLE], "Supply Assistant") then "Supply Assistant" else (each if Text.StartsWith([POS_TITLE], "NCC Rep") then "NCC Rep" else [POS_TITLE]))
```

How do I either get this to work when adding a new column above, or, better, replace multiple values based on the start of the text in the existing column?

If I can get the second one working I'll be able to modify for the remaining titles.

Thanks in advance for any help, but please, keep it simple - all of the searching I've done on this has left me baffled!

Comment: Well, I took the dog for a walk and came back and figured it out - some brackets in the wrong places: = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value1", "Title", each if Text.StartsWith([POS_TITLE], "Supply Assistant")
then "Supply Assistant" else if Text.StartsWith([POS_TITLE], "NCC Rep") then "NCC Rep" else if Text.StartsWith([POS_TITLE], "Machine Operator") then "Machine Operator" else [POS_TITLE])